# Window.open sends the call to the servlet twice

Tags: javascript, servlets, microsoft-edge, window.open

I am using window.open to display a pdf report in a new window.
I have a link in my app which when clicked calls a javascript function. 
Inside that function, another function is being called to which name and  relative url argument is being passed. This function calls window.open with the passed arguments like this

```
window.open(url,name,'toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width='+width+',height='+height);
```

This url is to a servlet which does some loading of the report and then write to the output stream from the pdf file.
This runs fine in Chrome or Firefox. However when the same report is loaded using Microsoft Edge the new window keeps loading. When i debugged it, I found out that the servlet in the relative url is being called twice. It first gets called, it carries out the execution of code, flushes the outputstream. the execution ends here in other browsers but with edge, the new window is empty with the correct url and then another call is sent to the same servlet and the execution repeats. And after the execution finishes the new window is empty as before.
I have tried different solutions from SO. 
I was suggested to open the window without a url and then redirect/reassign the url. 
I am not sure if this is an issue with window.open or some thing else is misbehaving in my code. But if it was the code then how would it work fine in other browsers.
I was reading that this call is asynchronous, So i was thinking that this might be related to it so i looked for a solution to send a window.open call synchronously but could not find a way and i am thinking that it can not be done.
I have tried quite a few options looking at SO, but to no avail.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look, seems to be fixed in a newer version of IE.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7277069/